# How to generate jhipster view?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jhipster, code-generation

How to generate jhipster view?

Or everything with view.

I tried to make jdl based generation - works well, but no views.

```
jhipster import-jdl jhipster-jdl.jh
```

Comment: Did you generate a monolith or gateway? Microservices don't have a UI

Comment: this is an answer - post it, thx!

Comment: I tried to add compile "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server", but still there is no @EnableEurekaServer import, could u help with this also?

Comment: Normally you would use the JHipster Registry as the Eureka server https://www.jhipster.tech/jhipster-registry/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the "Gateway" and "Monolith" application types generate a view.  Microservices only contain backend Java code to serve an API.